# Android - How to set numeric EditText to a specified number of digits

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want an EditText to contain exactly 8 digits (like bank accounts). Of course in addition to :

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Is there an option in XML or do I have to manage this programmatically ?

Comment: You're going to have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Programmatically.**

Also, you can save time by using existing library [EditText with validation](https://github.com/vekexasia/android-edittext-validator). You can use a `regex` type with following pattern `[0-9]{8}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way just in xml.
You have to validate it programmatically.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // validation code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line in your `EditText`:

```
android:maxLength="8"
```

Comment: The user can however enter only 2 digits. I want exactly 8

Comment: can you try setting min to 8 and max to 8 ... probably that assure user enters 8 digits

Answer (score 0):

This is my phone edit text:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/ObligatoryEditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/etxtClientPhone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/hub_blue_normal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:maxLength="8"/>
```

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!!

Comment: Not what I'm looking for

Answer (score -1):

Change input type in decimal, then set maxLength="8".

```
android:inputType="decimal"
android:maxLength="8"
```